# How can I read a .wav file,and save it in other name by 2 push buttons?

Tags: matlab, wav

This is my Open and Save button codes:

```
% --- Executes on button press in Openb.
function Openb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Openb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global filename pathname y fs nbits;
[filename, pathname]=uigetfile('*.wav', 'Select a wave file');
[y, fs, nbits] = wavread(fullfile(pathname, filename));
guidata(hObject,handels);


% --- Executes on button press in Saveb.
function Saveb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Saveb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global filename pathname y fs nbits;
[pathname filename]=uiputfile('*.wave', 'Choose a name to save file');
wavwrite(handles.y,fs,nbits,fullfile(pathname,filename));
guidata(hObject,handels);
```

And get these Errors:

Reference to non-existent field 'y'.

Error in M_player>Saveb_Callback (line 124)
wavwrite(handles.y,fs,nbits,fullfile(pathname,filename));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in M_player (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)M_player('Saveb_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Ive solved my problems by editing my code to following code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in Openb.
function Openb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Openb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global filename pathname y fs nbits;
[filename, pathname]=uigetfile('*.wav', 'Select a wave file');
[y, fs, nbits] = wavread(fullfile(pathname, filename));


% --- Executes on button press in Saveb.
function Saveb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Saveb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global filename pathname y fs nbits;
[filename pathname]=uiputfile('*.wave', 'Choose a name to save file');
wavwrite(y , [pathname,filename]);
```

Comment: Also you use `handles.y` in `Openb_Callback` without initializing it in the handles structure or storing it. Maybe you mean the global `y`.

Comment: I hope your error is not just due to the typo: `wavwrtie` instead of `wavwrite` (_in `Saveb_Callback`_). Also, `[START STOP]` are not defined anywhere (and not global).

Comment: Your variables are still inconsistent. Go through all of your inputs and outputs and make sure they are stored and recalled correctly.

Comment: you still try to use `handles.y` instead of `y` somewhere, and in two places you misspelled `handles` (you wrote `handels`). By the way with your given code, these 2 lines `guidata(hObject,handels);` are useless anyway, you can remove them before you generate more error.

Comment: Ive changed y.handles to y, and correct misspelled words, and removed guidata()'s but still have these errors:

Error using wavwrite>OpenWaveWrite (line 169)
Unable to open file. Reason: Invalid argument

Error in wavwrite (line 95)
fid = OpenWaveWrite(wavefile);

Comment: Error in M_player>Saveb_Callback (line 124)
wavwrite(y,fs,nbits,fullfile(pathname,filename));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in M_player (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)M_player('Saveb_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback